# How to evaluate multiple density estimations in one space?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, model-evaluation, density-estimation

Let's say we have several users, each represented by a set of document vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We fit the generative distributions using one Gaussian mixture model for each user. The goal is to use this density to recommend new documents to the user. How can we evaluate the quality of those estimated densities?

My first bet would be to perform k-fold cross validation on the documents of each user. Fit the GMM to the training data. Construct the test data with the hold-out documents as positive examples $P$ and the documents of all other users as negative examples $N$. Compute the cross-entropy as $-\sum_{x\in P}\log q(x)-\sum_{x\in N}\log (1-q(x))$.

Another approach would be to again to k-fold cross validation for each user and fit the GMM on the training data. Then sample $n\geq|P|$ times from the generative model and pick the nearest neighbors from the set of all documents. Then count how many of the documents in $P$ were sampled.

Comment: The answer will depend on the purpose of the quality measure. Can you clarify? It sounds like you want to construct a classifier for attributing documents to users; is that right? If so, is predictive performance the goal, or something else?

Comment: @user20160 Of course. The goal is to recommend new documents to the user. I would argue this is different from a predictive model (it doesn't take time dependencies into account, etc). However, predictive accuracy might still be valid measure with enough samples (I appended this approach to the question).